# Bitmap is not being drawn after setting BitmapFactory.options

Tags: android, android-bitmap

Im trying to load bitmap more efficiently, as per: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

However when I calculate the sample size & pass that recommendation to BitmapFactory.Options the bitmap is no longer drawn? The sample size being passed is 1 therefore no scaling is required.

Here is my AsyncTask that attempts to download an image via inputstream & return a bitmap:

```
package com.xyz.InboxManager;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.xyz.helpers.ImageUtility;

public class GetBitmapDataFromInputStreamTask extends AsyncTask<InputStream,Void,Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;

    public GetBitmapDataFromInputStreamTask(ImageView _imageView) {
        super();

        imageView = _imageView;

    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(InputStream... inputStreams) {

        InputStream is = inputStreams[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (is != null) {

            ImageUtility.ImageScalingData imageScalingData = ImageUtility.optimalDimension(ImageUtility.bitmapWidthAndHeight(is).outWidth,ImageUtility.bitmapWidthAndHeight(is).outHeight,ImageUtility.dpScreenWidth(),ImageUtility.dpScreenHeight());
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = imageScalingData.getSampleSize();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap!=null && imageView!=null)
        {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }


    }
}
```

**This class ImageUtility is used to calculate the Image Scaling factor for a Bitmap, based on https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap:**

```
package com.xyz.helpers;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.InputStream;

import com.xyz.Application.NgfrApp;

public class ImageUtility {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageUtility";

    public static float dpScreenHeight()
    {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    }

    public static float dpScreenWidth()
    {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        return  displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    }

    public static BitmapFactory.Options bitmapWidthAndHeight (InputStream is)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        //set back to false
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return options;
    }

    public static ImageScalingData optimalDimension(double imageWidth, double imageHeight, double screenWidth, double screenHeight, float imageToScreenScaleFactor)
    {

        Log.i(TAG,"imageWidth: "+imageWidth+",imageHeight:"+imageHeight+",screenWidth:"+screenWidth+",screenHeight:"+screenHeight);

        ImageScalingData imageScalingData = null;
        double imageFrameHeight = screenHeight * imageToScreenScaleFactor;
        double imageFrameWidth = screenWidth * imageToScreenScaleFactor;
        int counter = 1;

            //image is larger than frame , decrease dimension
            if (imageHeight > screenHeight || imageWidth > screenWidth)
            {
              while (imageHeight > screenHeight || imageWidth > screenWidth)
              {
                  imageHeight = imageHeight / 2;
                  imageWidth = imageWidth / 2;
                  counter *= 2;
              }

                imageScalingData = new ImageScalingData(imageWidth,imageHeight,counter);
            }
            else
            {
                //same size do nothing
                imageScalingData = new ImageScalingData(imageWidth,imageHeight,counter);
            }

        return imageScalingData;
    }

    public static class ImageScalingData {

        private  double width;
        private double height;
        private int sampleSize;

        private ImageScalingData(double _width, double _height, int _sampleSize)
        {
            width = _width;
            height = _height;
            sampleSize = _sampleSize;
        }

        public double getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public double getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public int getSampleSize() {
            return sampleSize;
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed my logs , were showing image height & width has 0 , which doesn't make sense.

I/ImageUtility: **imageWidth: 0.0,imageHeight:0.0**,screenWidth:360.0,screenHeight:640.0

When I removed the code in async class GetBitmapDataFromInputStreamTask, everthing works however Im not down sampling & that degrades performance when you have 100 messages in the   :
inbox.

```
  ImageUtility.ImageScalingData imageScalingData = ImageUtility.optimalDimension(ImageUtility.bitmapWidthAndHeight(is).outWidth,ImageUtility.bitmapWidthAndHeight(is).outHeight,ImageUtility.dpScreenWidth(),ImageUtility.dpScreenHeight());
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = imageScalingData.getSampleSize();
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: You aren't actually using `options` for the `decodeStream()` call in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes your right! Now why are height & width coming back as 0? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I think I see it. You're using the same `InputStream` repeatedly; e.g., in `bitmapWidthAndHeight()`. `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` will leave the stream position at wherever it stops after decoding. After the first `decodeStream()` call, it's at the end of the stream, so the subsequent calls don't really do anything.

Comment: Yes, that the 2nd reason, Thanks. Although my performance is worse now! also are still I/ImageUtility: imageWidth: 0.0,imageHeight:0.0,screenWidth:360.0,screenHeight:640.0. Why is height & width coming back as 0 ???

Comment: Dunno. I don't know what changes you've made, where the stream is coming from, if it's used before the `AsyncTask`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. Your answer to 1st question is right & for 2nd question I must pass in BitmapFactory.Options options to the decodeStream() like this BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options); Now im able to get weight & height of the image data inside the InputStream. Thanks